# Change Gateway doesn't work on Windows 7

Tags: windows, networking, windows-7, local-area-network, ipv4

This PC was configured with 192.168.6.1. But I tried to change it to 192.168.6.51. Although route print showed the default gateway is 192.168.6.51, but the packets next hop is 192.168.6.1.

```
IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
      0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0     192.168.6.51     192.168.6.50    261
    127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
    127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  192.168.6.0    255.255.255.0         On-link      192.168.6.50    261
 192.168.6.50  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.6.50    261
192.168.6.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.6.50    261
    224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
    224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      192.168.6.50    261
255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.6.50    261
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
None
```

But when tried tracert 8.8.8.8, the next hop is still 192.168.6.1.

```
 Tracing route to 8.8.8.8 over a maximum of 30 hops

1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  192.168.6.1
2     1 ms     4 ms    <1 ms  ^C
```

Comment: I believe Windows may cache the routing.  Have you rebooted?  Or maybe if you issue `netsh interface ip delete destinationcache`

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I tired this already. It doesn't work. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try resetting the winsock catalog. This should reset the adapter and all the cachings.

```
    netsh winsock reset
```

After this, you will need to restart the machine.

Comment: Do you have to drag up an old, low-quality question and give a very basic and generic answer?